# How to invert a NAND gate IC and have it work like an AND gate IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-gates, inverter, breadboard, nand

I have created this circuit design using tinkercad. I thought I had two 74HC08 IC:s. Turns out I only have one. Can I replace the second 74HC08 with an inverted 74HC00 and if so how do I do this? If it is not possible what other IC can I use from my parts list and still get the same output as in my truth table? Can anyone show how this would be done on the breadboard using tinkercad or any other virtual breadboard?

Truth Table:

[image]

Available parts list. Note, only one of each IC type available:

[image]

Logisim design:

[image]

Circuit design built on tinkercad (slightly changed from the Logisim design above but output is the same as truth table):

[image]

Comment: You don't need all these inverters. For each input that needs to be inverted, you only need to do it once, and connect the output of this inverter to all the respective AND inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a NAND gate to an AND gate, add an inverter to the output.  Think of it as the bubble on the NAND gate and the bubble on the inverter cancelling out each other.

This will add 1 gate delay to signals going through it, not an issue in your case.

Answer (score 0):

$$\bar A \bar B D + \bar A \bar B C + B C \bar D$$
$$\bar A \bar B D + \bar A \bar B C (\bar D + D) + B C \bar D$$
$$\bar A \bar B D + \bar A \bar B C \bar D  + \bar A \bar B C D+ B C \bar D$$
$$\bar A \bar B D (1 + C) + B C \bar D (1 + \bar A) $$
$$\bar A \bar B D + B C \bar D$$

\$\bar A \bar B C \$ gets absorbed into your other terms.  Your expression has four terms, so you only need 4 3-input ANDs.  You have 3.

You can use your 4-input AND as 3-inputs.  Tie unused input to Vcc.

Use 3 74HC32's to create your 4 input OR.  OR two of the terms, then OR the outputs.